# Defining the order of operations in an http.get() request - sync/async issue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, get, synchronous

I'm retrieving a web address as a URL parameter and then displaying whether the address returns a status code of 200 or not. The trouble is, it seems to only work after a couple seconds--the first time I run it, the code assigning 'mystatus' doesn't seem to be working properly. I feel like there is an issue with the order in which I am running things, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
var express = require("express");
var moment = require("moment");
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var moment = require("moment");
var http = require("http");
var app=express();
var mystatus="";

app.get('/new/:name*', function(req,res){

    //detect if name is a URL
    //return output
    http.get("http:"+req.params[0], function(thisres){
        if (thisres.statusCode != 200){
            mystatus = "Could not load";
        }
        else {
            mystatus = "Loaded!";
        }
    }).on('error', function(e){
        console.error(e);
    })
    res.json({url_part1: req.params.name,
        url_part2: req.params[0],
        status: mystatus
        });
})

app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("App listening on port 8080")
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running your code node in the promise, so both `http.get` and `res.json` are running at the exact same time, so whichever one finishes first it doesn't matter.

Move the `res.json` response into the promise body of `http.get` so it will send the response when it gets it

```
var express = require("express");
var moment = require("moment");
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var moment = require("moment");
var http = require("http");
var app=express();
var mystatus="";

app.get('/new/:name*', function(req,res){

    //detect if name is a URL
    //return output
    http.get("http:"+req.params[0], function(thisres){
        if (thisres.statusCode != 200){
            mystatus = "Could not load";
        }
        else {
            mystatus = "Loaded!";
        }

        res.json({url_part1: req.params.name,
        url_part2: req.params[0],
        status: mystatus
        });
    }).on('error', function(e){
        console.error(e);
    })
})

app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("App listening on port 8080")
});
```